# Java Spring Hibernate SQL logs not logging in appender

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I have a Java Spring application using:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

in my application.properties file.

I use logback/logstash for all of my logs, but the Hibernate logs are not going into the appender. I have this in my logback.xml file:

```
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="json" />
    </logger>
```

With my appender (json) being:

```
    <appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">

            <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</timestampPattern>
            <includeMdcKeyName>RID</includeMdcKeyName>
            <mdcKeyFieldName>RID=rid</mdcKeyFieldName>

            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>timestamp</timestamp>
                <level>level</level>
                <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
                <logger>logger</logger>
                <version>[ignore]</version>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

So a "normal" log looks like this: (replaced the actual stuff with `{...}`)

```
{"timestamp":"2023-04-20T16:11:25.133-0600","message":"My normal log message","logger":"{...}","thread_name":"{...}","level":"INFO","rid":"{...}"}
```

However my Hibernate logs still look like:

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM my_table mt WHERE mt.name = ?
```

As you can see it does not seem to go to my appender for formatting. It also doesn't show the values, just `?`

How do I fix this so my Hibernate logs look more like:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-04-20T16:11:25.133-0600","message":"Hibernate: SELECT * FROM my_table mt WHERE mt.name = ?","logger":"{...}","thread_name":"{...}","level":"INFO","rid":"{...}"}
```

but also with the actual values, not "`?`" ?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The property `hibernate.show_sql` does not direct its output through any logging framework. It always sends its output directly to the console.

Instead, you should use the log category `org.hibernate.SQL` if you want the SQL logged via a logging framework.